# 'not is enabled' doesn't match the selected view : While testing buttons enable and disable functionality

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, cucumber, android-espresso

Testing scenario:

- Click on start button and disable it immediately to avoid multiple clicks
- Re-enable it after getting response from server

feature file

```
@smoke
@one
Scenario: Check start button gets enabled after the server response
Given There is a scheduled route
Then I click on scheduled route at 0
Then I click on the start button
Then I should see start button disabled
Then I should see start button enabled after server response
```

MainScreenRobot.kt

```
fun checkStartButtonDisabled() {
    SystemClock.sleep(1000)
    onView(withId(R.id.routeDetailGreenButton)).check(matches((isDisplayed())))
    onView(withId(R.id.routeDetailGreenButton)).check(matches(not(isEnabled())))
}

fun checkStartButtonEnabled() {
    onView(withId(R.id.routeDetailGreenButton)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    onView(withId(R.id.routeDetailGreenButton)).check(matches(isEnabled()))
}
```

MyFragment

```
private fun disableButtons(){
    configureToolbarButton(R.id.routeDetailGreenButton, isButtonEnabled = false)
    if (isToolbarButtonVisible(R.id.routeDetailGreyButton)) {
        configureToolbarButton(R.id.routeDetailGreyButton, isButtonEnabled = false)
    }
}

private fun enableButtons(){
    configureToolbarButton(R.id.routeDetailGreenButton, isButtonEnabled = true)
    if (isToolbarButtonVisible(R.id.routeDetailGreyButton)) {
        configureToolbarButton(R.id.routeDetailGreyButton, isButtonEnabled = true)
    }
}
private fun startRouteAndToggleButtonState() {
    /* Disable buttons until we get a response back that the action is done */
    disableButtons()
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        /* Call to start route */
        routeDetailViewModel.startRoute().collect {
            /* Re-enable buttons when action is complete */
            enableButtons()
        }
    }
}
```

MainSteps.kt file

```
@Then
("I should see start button disabled")
fun i_should_see_start_button_disabled() {
robot.checkStartButtonDisabled()
}
```

Test fails at

> onView(withId(R.id.routeDetailGreenButton)).check(matches(not(isEnabled())))

```
androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'not is 
enabled' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: not is enabled
Got: "AppCompatButton{id=2131231133, res-name=routeDetailGreenButton, visibility=VISIBLE, 
width=133, height=64, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is- 
clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout- 
requested=false, is-selected=false, layout- 
params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@e0debb6, tag=null, root-is-layout- 
requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=2.0, text=Start, input-type=0, ime- 
target=false, has-links=false}"
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for the test class where `checkStartButtonDisabled` is called?

Comment: Added MainSteps.kt file where above function is called

Comment: Do you have a mechanism to delay the server response to give Espresso enough time to check `checkStartButtonDisabled`?

Comment: @JustTheHighlights I think this input has helped me in resolving my issue but apart from this I also had to add a delay in my test case before enabling the button. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Input from @JustTheHighlights was helpful to resolve this issue.

I added a small delay just before re-enabling my button as shown below

```
private fun startRouteAndToggleButtonState() {

    /* Disable start button until we get a response back that the action is done */
    disableStartButton()

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        /* Call to start route */
        routeDetailViewModel.startRoute().run {
            /* Re-enable buttons when action is complete */
            delay(500)
            enableStartButton()
        }
    }
}
```

Apart from this another important step was to add sleep in my test case as well

```
fun checkStartButtonEnabled() {
    SystemClock.sleep(500)
    onView(withId(R.id.routeDetailGreenButton)).check(matches(isEnabled()))
}
```